# Add empty columns to a dataframe with specified names from a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df`, with a a number of columns of data already. I have a vector, `namevector`, full of strings. I need empty columns added to `df` with the names of the columns from `namevector`.

I am trying to add columns with this for loop, iterating over each string in `namevector`.

```
for (i in length(namevector)) {
  df[, i] <- NA
}
```

but am left with this error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = NA) :
> new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Alternatively, I have thought of creating an empty dataframe with the correct names, then `cbind`-ing the two dataframes together but am not sure how to go about coding this.

How would I go about resolving this?

Comment: I think maybe you meant `seq_len(length(namevector))` or something similar.

Comment: you mean `for (i in (seq_len(length(namevector)) + ncol(df))) ...` then change the column names.

Comment: @JamesPringle `seq_len(length(...))` is a longcut to `seq_along()`

Comment: @JamesPringle Thanks, I forgot about adding the offset since they're adding new columns.

Comment: Does anyone know a tidyverse way to do this?

Comment: @rilkehayden See add_column()

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The **problem** with your code is in the line:

```
for(i in length(namevector))
```

You need to ask yourself: what is `length(namevector)`? It's one number. So essentially you're saying:

```
for(i in 11)
df[,i] <- NA
```

Or more simply:

```
df[,11] <- NA
```

**That's** why you're getting an error. What you want is:

```
for(i in namevector)
    df[,i] <- NA
```

Or more simply:

```
df[,namevector] <- NA
```

Comment: Please consider moving `df[,namevector] <- NA` to the top of your answer, since that is the general solution

Answer (score 30):

```
set.seed(1)
example <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1), col2 = rnorm(10, 2, 3))
namevector <- c("col3", "col4")
example[ , namevector] <- NA

example
#          col1       col2 col3 col4
# 1  -0.6264538  6.5353435   NA   NA
# 2   0.1836433  3.1695297   NA   NA
# 3  -0.8356286  0.1362783   NA   NA
# 4   1.5952808 -4.6440997   NA   NA
# 5   0.3295078  5.3747928   NA   NA
# 6  -0.8204684  1.8651992   NA   NA
# 7   0.4874291  1.9514292   NA   NA
# 8   0.7383247  4.8315086   NA   NA
# 9   0.5757814  4.4636636   NA   NA
# 10 -0.3053884  3.7817040   NA   NA
```

Comment: The `set.seed(1)` doesn't seem strictly necessary.

Comment: The `set.seed` was only added so the example data.frame will be the same if a user runs the code. Technically, the `rnorm` is not necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, so the random numbers are the same for everyone runs the code. I see.

Answer (score 17):

The below works for me

```
dataframe[,"newName"] <- NA
```

Make sure to add `""` for new name string.

Comment: The OP has requested to *Add empty columns to a dataframe with specified names **from a vector***. So, he wants to add *many* columns. Your answer does only add *one* column and the name is *not* taken from the variable `namevector` as requested. Therefore, please review your post or consider to delete it. Thank you.

Comment: you can always run a loop for list of columns

Comment: Right but then your answer is identical to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18215216/3817004) which suggests `for(i in namevector) df[,i] <- NA`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the base R solution, but here is a `tidyverse` solution. Below uses `mutate`, but the syntax is the same if you were to use `tibble::add_column`:

```
library(dplyr)

new_columns <- c("A", "B", "C")

iris %>% 
  mutate(!!!setNames(rep(NA, length(new_columns)), new_columns))
```

The splice operator uses the name-value pair from `setNames` to create the columns.

If you had name-value pairs in a list already then you can simply do:

```
new_columns <- list(A = NA, B = 1, C = "c")

iris %>% 
  mutate(!!!new_columns)
```

If the length of each list element is 1 then its value is recycled. Otherwise, it needs to have the same length as the data frame (e.g. `list(A = 1:150`).

Answer (score 1):

A different way to add empty columns to a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(name0 = c(1,2,3))
namevector <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

sapply(namevector, function(x){df[x] <<- numeric()})
```

- The for loop is eliminated with the <<- operator.
- In many of these examples, the type associated with the new empty column will be a logical; however, by specifying numeric() the type will be numeric. Other types, like double() or character(), could be specified.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
df <- do.call("cbind", list(df, rep(list(NA),length(namevector))))
colnames(df)[-1*(1:(ncol(df) - length(namevector)))] <- namevector
```