# Populate multiple columns by values in one column

Tags: r

I haven't been able to find a solution to this so far... This one came the closest: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214395/r-add-empty-columns-to-a-dataframe-with-specified-names-from-a-vector)

Here is a small subset of my dataframe, df:

```
ANIMAL(chr)    MARKER(int)    GENOTYPE(int)
"1012828"      1550978        0
"1012828"      1550982        2
"1012828"      1550985        1
"1012830"      1550982        0
"1012830"      1550985        2
"1012830"      1550989        2
```

And what I want is this...

```
ANIMAL        MARKER_1550978    MARKER_1550982    MARKER_1550985    MARKER_1550989
"1012828"     0                 2                 1                 NA
"1012830"     NA                0                 2                 2
```

My thought, initially was to create columns for each marker according to the referenced question

```
markers <- unique(df$MARKER)
df[,markers] <- NA
```

since I can't have integers for column names in R. I added "MARKER_" to each new column so it would work:

`df$MARKER <- paste("MARKER_",df$MARKER)
markers <- unique(df$MARKER)
df[,markers] <- NA`

Now I have all my new columns, but with the same number of rows. I'll have no problem getting rid of unnecessary rows and columns, but how would I correctly populate my new columns with their correct GENOTYPE by MARKER and ANIMAL? Am guessing one-or-more of these: indexing, match, %in%... but don't know where to start. Searching for these in stackoverflow did not yield anything that seemed pertinent to my challenge.

Comment: You want to spread your dataframe from narrow to wide. Check out `tidyr::spread`

Comment: specifically `tidyr::spread(df, MARKER, GENOTYPE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is a very common dataframe operation, commonly called "spreading", or "widening". The inverse of this operation is "gathering". Check out this [handy cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf), specifically the part on reshaping data.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% spread(MARKER, GENOTYPE)
#>    ANIMAL 1550978 1550982 1550985 1550989
#> 1 1012828       0       2       1      NA
#> 2 1012830      NA       0       2       2
```

Comment: thanks so much, works beautifully!