How to create sequential columns with one function in R
I have a dataset that needs to be modified to include 30 additional columns (up to field7_30), none of which will contain data. Is there way to write this without using 30 separate mutate functions?
df<- as.data.frame(ID = c(1:5),field7_01 = c(0,0,1,1,3))

df<-df%>%
mutate(field7_02 = '', field7_03='')


This sounds like it might be an XY problem, where you are seeking a specific implementation where an entirely different approach might be simpler. Why do you need 30 additional blank columns?

Sounds pretty similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214395/add-empty-columns-to-a-dataframe-with-specified-names-from-a-vector.  Does that address it for you?

the additional blank columns are a requirement of the agency I'm submitting the data to, but I see your point. And yes, the referenced question does offer some helpful details. (I'd have to add a paste0() function which is fine) thank you.

Here is one tidyverse possibility:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  mutate(!!!map(set_names(str_c("field7_", str_pad(2:30, 2, "left", "0"))), ~ ''))

As you can see this is not nearly as succinct as the base R solution.

You may generate those column names using sprintf :
df[sprintf('field7_%02i', 2:30)] <- ''


I am unfamiliar with the sprintf() function prior to this. This does accomplish my stated objective. Is there a way to integrate it into dplyr?

It is a general purpose string formatting function in base R, where in this case the %02i is serving the same task as str_c + str_pad in the other answer.
